# Отменить HttpSendRequest в WinInet

Tags: c#, c++, delphi, winapi, wininet

Часть кода опустил для читабельности, но суть, думаю ясна. Вызываю загрузку страницы через WinInet, на форму вешаю кнопку отмены. InternetCloseHandle(FHttpRequest) не решает проблемы. Где-то читал, что отменять запросы можно только в асинхронном соединении, но при установки ключа INTERNET_FLAG_ASYNC у меня вообще не выгружает страницу...

```
FHttpSession:= InternetOpen(PChar(FClientName), INTERNET_OPEN_TYPE_PRECONFIG, nil, nil, 0);
FHttpConnect:= InternetConnect(FHttpSession, PChar(hostname), Flags_connection, nil, nil, INTERNET_SERVICE_HTTP, 0, 0);
FHttpRequest:= HttpOpenRequest(FHttpConnect, PChar(FMethod), PChar(script), HTTP_VERSION, nil, nil, Flags_Request, 0);
HttpSendRequest(httpRequest, nil, 0, nil, 0); // Вот тут подвисает
InternetCloseHandle(FHttpRequest);
InternetCloseHandle(FHttpConnect);
InternetCloseHandle(FHttpSession);
```

В проекте 3 модуля: главный, модуль потока и что-то вроде обертки над wininet. На главной форме на кнопку вешаю такой обработчик:

```
procedure TFrmTesting.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if Assigned(ThreadWinInetReq) then
  begin
    ThreadWinInetReq.StopThread;
    ThreadWinInetReq.Terminate;
  end;
end;
```

Событие StopThread:

```
procedure TThreadWinInetReq.StopThread;
begin
  if Assigned(FClient) then
  begin
    FClient.Stop:= True;
    FClient.CancelRequest;
  end;
  Terminate;
end;
```

Событие CancelRequest:

```
procedure TWinInet.CancelRequest;
begin
  InternetCloseHandle(FHttpRequest);
  InternetCloseHandle(FHttpConnect);
  InternetCloseHandle(FHttpSession);
end;
```

Догадываюсь, что где-то что-то не так передаю...

**Дополнение**

Вот так работает, но иногда в асинхронном режиме выдает пустую страницу

```
unit UnitWinInet;

interface

uses
  System.SysUtils, System.Types, WinInet, Winapi.Windows;

type

  TWinInet = class
    private
      FHWND: THandle; // Хэндл вызывающего приложения
      FClientName, // Имя клиента
      FParam, // параметры запроса (которые после ?)
      FMethod, // GET, POST и др.
      FType_Access, // mime type и проч, если установлен в '', то используется по умолчанию
      FLogin, // логин
      FPass: string; // пароль
      FPostData: boolean; //True - передача параметров запроса через post data, False - через строку запроса
      FStop: boolean; // вспомогательная переменная отв. за остановку скачки
      FHttpSession, FHttpConnect, FHttpRequest: HINTERNET;
      FAsync: Boolean;
      procedure SetMethod(AMethod: string);
    public
      property HWND: THandle read FHWND write FHWND;
      property ClientName: string read FClientName write FClientName;
      property Param: string read FParam write FParam;
      property Method: string read FMethod write SetMethod;
      property Type_Access: string read FType_Access write FType_Access;
      property Login: string read FLogin write FLogin;
      property Pass: string read FPass write FPass;
      property PostData: boolean read FPostData write FPostData;
      property Async: boolean read FAsync write FAsync;
      function GetHTTP(AURL: string): AnsiString;
      procedure CancelRequest;
      constructor Create(AHWND: THandle);
  end;

implementation

uses
  Vcl.Dialogs, System.Classes, UnitTesting;
var
  completed, BOK: boolean;

procedure TWinInet.CancelRequest;
begin
  FStop:= True;
  InternetCloseHandle(FHttpRequest);
  InternetCloseHandle(FHttpConnect);
  InternetCloseHandle(FHttpSession);
  InternetSetOption(nil, INTERNET_OPTION_SETTINGS_CHANGED, nil, 0);
end;

constructor TWinInet.Create(AHWND: THandle);
begin
  FHWND:= AHWND;
  FClientName:= 'WinInet';
  FMethod:= 'GET';
  FType_Access:= 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlenDELPHId' + #13#10 +
                   'Content-Length:' + IntToStr(length(FParam));
  FPostData:= False;
  FAsync:= True;
end;

procedure TWinInet.SetMethod(AMethod: string);
begin
  FMethod:= UpperCase(AMethod);
end;

function TWinInet.GetHTTP(AURL: string): AnsiString;

  function GetHostName(AUrl: string): string;
  var
    s: string;
  begin // Имя хоста
    if Pos('https://', AUrl) > 0 then
      s:= 'https://'
    else
      if Pos('http://', AUrl) > 0 then
        s:= 'http://'
      else
        s:= EmptyStr;
    if s <> EmptyStr then
      if Pos(s, AUrl) > 0 then
        Delete(AUrl, 1, Length(s));
    if Pos('/', AUrl) > 0 then
      SetLength(AUrl, Pos('/', AUrl) - 1);
    Result:= AUrl;
  end;

  function GetScriptName(AUrl, AHostname: string): string;
  begin // URL после имени хоста
    Result:= EmptyStr;
    Delete(AUrl, 1, Pos(AHostname, AUrl) + Length(AHostname));
    Result:= AUrl;
  end;

  procedure SetFlags(AUrl: string; out Flags_connection, Flags_Request: Cardinal);
  begin // Определяем https или http
    if Pos('https://', AUrl) > 0 then
    begin
      Flags_connection:= INTERNET_DEFAULT_HTTPS_PORT;
      Flags_Request:= INTERNET_FLAG_RELOAD
                   or INTERNET_FLAG_NO_CACHE_WRITE
                   or INTERNET_FLAG_SECURE
                   or INTERNET_FLAG_IGNORE_CERT_CN_INVALID
                   or INTERNET_FLAG_IGNORE_CERT_DATE_INVALID
                   //or INTERNET_FLAG_KEEP_CONNECTION
    end else
      begin
        Flags_connection:= INTERNET_DEFAULT_HTTP_PORT;
        Flags_Request:= INTERNET_FLAG_RELOAD
                     or INTERNET_FLAG_IGNORE_CERT_CN_INVALID
                     or INTERNET_FLAG_NO_CACHE_WRITE
                     or INTERNET_FLAG_PRAGMA_NOCACHE
                     or INTERNET_FLAG_KEEP_CONNECTION;
      end;
  end;

  function GetResponseHeader(const hRequest: Pointer): string;
  var
    dwSize, Index: DWORD;
    szBuff: array [0..1024] of Char;
  begin // Возвращает заголовок ответа сервера в виде строк с CR/LF
    Index:= 0;
    dwSize:= SizeOf(szBuff);
    HttpQueryInfo(hRequest, HTTP_QUERY_RAW_HEADERS_CRLF, @szBuff, dwSize, Index);
    Result:= PChar(@szBuff);
  end;

  function GetStatus(const hRequest: Pointer): DWORD;
  var
    dwSize, dwStatus, Index: DWORD;
  begin // Возвращает заголовок ответа сервера в виде строк с CR/LF
    // Возвращает код статуса HTTP из заголовка ответа
    Index:= 0;
    dwSize:= SizeOf(dwStatus);
    HttpQueryInfo(hRequest, HTTP_QUERY_STATUS_CODE or HTTP_QUERY_FLAG_NUMBER, @dwStatus, dwSize, Index);
    Result:= dwStatus;
  end;

  function AddSecurityFlags(httpReq: Pointer): Boolean;
  var
    dwSize, dwFlags: DWORD;
  begin
    Result:= False;
    dwSize:= SizeOf(dwFlags);     // Get the current security flags
    if (InternetQueryOption(httpReq, INTERNET_OPTION_SECURITY_FLAGS, @dwFlags, dwSize)) then
    begin // Add desired flags
       dwFlags:= dwFlags
         or SECURITY_FLAG_IGNORE_UNKNOWN_CA
         or SECURITY_FLAG_IGNORE_CERT_CN_INVALID
         or SECURITY_FLAG_IGNORE_CERT_DATE_INVALID
         or SECURITY_FLAG_IGNORE_REVOCATION;
       Result:= (InternetSetOption(httpReq,
              INTERNET_OPTION_SECURITY_FLAGS,
              @dwFlags,
              dwSize));
    end
  end;

  function SendRequest(httpRequest: Pointer; AType_Access, AParam: string): boolean;
  begin
    Result:= False;
    if (FStop = False) then
      case FPostData of
        False: Result:= HttpSendRequest(httpRequest, nil, 0, nil, 0);
        True: Result:= HttpSendRequest(httpRequest, PChar(AType_Access), Length(AType_Access), PChar(AParam), Length(AParam));
      end;
  end;

  procedure StatusCallback(hInet: HINTERNET; Context: DWORD_PTR; Status: DWORD; pInformation: Pointer;
    InfoLength: DWORD); stdcall;
  var
    s: string;
  begin
    case Status of
      INTERNET_STATUS_CLOSING_CONNECTION: s:= 'Closing the connection to the server';
      INTERNET_STATUS_CONNECTED_TO_SERVER: s:= 'Successfully connected to the socket address: ';
      INTERNET_STATUS_CONNECTING_TO_SERVER: s:= 'Connecting to the socket address';
      INTERNET_STATUS_CONNECTION_CLOSED: s:= 'Successfully closed the connection to the server';
      INTERNET_STATUS_CTL_RESPONSE_RECEIVED: s:= 'Not implemented';
      INTERNET_STATUS_HANDLE_CLOSING: s:= 'This handle value has been terminated';
      INTERNET_STATUS_HANDLE_CREATED: s:= 'InternetConnect has created the new handle';
      INTERNET_STATUS_INTERMEDIATE_RESPONSE: s:=
        'Received an intermediate (100 level) status code message from the server';
      INTERNET_STATUS_NAME_RESOLVED: s:= 'Successfully found the IP address: ' + Format('%p',[pInformation]);
      INTERNET_STATUS_PREFETCH: s:= 'Not implemented';
      INTERNET_STATUS_RECEIVING_RESPONSE: s:= 'Waiting for the server to respond to a request ';
      INTERNET_STATUS_REDIRECT:
        begin
          s:= 'HTTP request is about to automatically redirect the request ' +
            Format('%p',[pInformation]);
          completed:= True;
        end;
      INTERNET_STATUS_REQUEST_COMPLETE:
        begin
          s:= 'An asynchronous operation has been completed';
          completed:= True;
          Sleep(5000);
        end;
      INTERNET_STATUS_REQUEST_SENT: s:= 'Successfully sent the information request to the server: ' +
        IntToStr(Integer(pInformation)) + ' Byte';
      INTERNET_STATUS_RESOLVING_NAME: s:= 'Looking up the IP address: ' + Format('%p',[pInformation]);
      INTERNET_STATUS_SENDING_REQUEST: s:= 'Sending the information request to the server.';
      INTERNET_STATUS_RESPONSE_RECEIVED:
        begin
          s:= 'Successfully received a response from the server: ' + IntToStr(Integer(pInformation)) + ' Byte';
          completed:= True;
        end;
      INTERNET_STATUS_STATE_CHANGE:
        begin
          s:= 'Moved between a secure (HTTPS) and a nonsecure (HTTP) site.';
          case DWORD(pInformation) of
            INTERNET_STATE_CONNECTED: s:= s + #13#10 + 'Connected state. Mutually exclusive with disconnected state.';
            INTERNET_STATE_DISCONNECTED: s:= s + #13#10 +
              'Disconnected state. No network connection could be established.';
            INTERNET_STATE_DISCONNECTED_BY_USER: s:= s + #13#10 + 'Disconnected by user request.';
            INTERNET_STATE_IDLE: s:= s + #13#10 + 'No network requests are being made by Windows Internet.';
            INTERNET_STATE_BUSY: s:= s + #13#10 + 'Network requests are being made by Windows Internet.';
          end;
        end;
    end;
    //FrmTesting.MmHTML.Lines.Add(s);
  end;

  function WaitAndStop: Boolean;
  begin // Цикл ожидания завершения запроса
    Result:= False;
    if FAsync then // применяется только в асинхронных вызовах
      while True do
      begin
        Sleep(1000);
        if FStop or completed then
        begin
          Result:= FStop;
          break;
        end;
      end;
  end;

var
  bytes, b, pos: Cardinal;
  hostname, script: string;
  Flags_connection, Flags_Request: Cardinal;
  DlgError, dwFlags: DWORD;
  Status: PFNInternetStatusCallback;
  iNetBuff : Internet_Buffers;
  lpReadBuff : Array [0..255] of AnsiChar;
const
  BufferSize = 1024*4;
begin
  Result:= EmptyAnsiStr;
  FStop:= False;
  hostname:= GetHostName(AURL); // имя хоста
  script:= GetScriptName(AURL, hostname); // скрипт
  // установка доп. параметров
  if not FPostData then // если передаем параметры через строку запроса, то
    if FParam <> EmptyStr then // дополняем скрипт
      if script[Length(script)] = '?' then
        script:= script + FParam
      else
        script:= script + '?' + FParam;
  try
    SetFlags(AURL, Flags_connection, Flags_Request); // Устанавливаем флаги (http или https)
    // Открываем сессию (инициализируем WinInet)
    case FAsync of
      False: dwFlags:= 0;
      True: dwFlags:= INTERNET_FLAG_ASYNC;
    end;
    FHttpSession:= InternetOpen(PChar(FClientName), INTERNET_OPEN_TYPE_PRECONFIG, nil, nil, dwFlags);
    if FAsync then // Устанавливаем callback, если подключение асинхронное
    begin
      Status:= InternetSetStatusCallback(FHttpSession,INTERNET_STATUS_CALLBACK(@StatusCallback));
      if NativeInt(Status) = INTERNET_INVALID_STATUS_CALLBACK then
      begin
        Result:= AnsiString('Callback function is not valid');
        Exit;
      end;
    end;
    if Assigned(FHttpSession) then // Проверяем хэндл
    try // Открываем соединение
      FHttpConnect:= InternetConnect(FHttpSession, PChar(hostname), Flags_connection, nil, nil, INTERNET_SERVICE_HTTP, 0, 1);
      if Assigned(FHttpConnect) then // Проверяем хэндл
      try // Открываем запрос (передаем остаток URL (скрипт GetScriptName) в ф-ю HttpOpenRequest под параметром lpszObjectName)
        FHttpRequest:= HttpOpenRequest(FHttpConnect, PChar(FMethod), PChar(script), HTTP_VERSION, nil, nil, Flags_Request, 1);
        if Assigned(FHttpRequest) then // Проверяем хэндл
        try
          AddSecurityFlags(FHttpRequest); // Добавляем флаги
          completed:= False;
          SendRequest(FHttpRequest, FType_Access, FParam); // Отправляем запрос
          if WaitAndStop then // цикл ожидания вызова callback функции для асинхронных вызовов
          begin
            Result:= AnsiString('Остановлено');
            Exit;
          end;
          if GetStatus(FHttpRequest) = HTTP_STATUS_DENIED then
          begin // Если необходима авторизация
            if FLogin <> EmptyStr then
            begin
              InternetSetOption(FHttpRequest, INTERNET_OPTION_USERNAME, PChar(FLogin), SizeOf(FLogin));
              InternetSetOption(FHttpRequest, INTERNET_OPTION_PASSWORD, PChar(FPass), SizeOf(FPass));
            end
              else
              begin
                DlgError:= InternetErrorDlg(FHWND, FHttpRequest,
                   ERROR_INTERNET_CLIENT_AUTH_CERT_NEEDED,
                   FLAGS_ERROR_UI_FILTER_FOR_ERRORS
                or FLAGS_ERROR_UI_FLAGS_GENERATE_DATA
                   //or FLAGS_ERROR_UI_SERIALIZE_DIALOGS
                or FLAGS_ERROR_UI_FLAGS_CHANGE_OPTIONS,
                   PPointer(nil)^ );
                if DlgError = 0 then
                begin
                  Result:= AnsiString('Доступ запрещен! Ввод учетных данных отменен.'
                   + sLineBreak + SysErrorMessage(GetLastError));
                  Exit;
                end;
              end;
            SendRequest(FHttpRequest, FType_Access, FParam);
            if WaitAndStop then // цикл ожидания вызова callback функции для асинхронных вызовов
            begin
              Result:= AnsiString('Остановлено');
              Exit;
            end;
          end;
          case FAsync of
            False: // Обычное чтение
              if GetStatus(FHttpRequest) = HTTP_STATUS_OK then
              begin
                pos:= 1;
                b:= 1;
                while (b > 0) and (FStop = False) do
                begin // Если количество данных 0 - генерируем исключение
                  if not InternetQueryDataAvailable(FHttpRequest, bytes, 0, 0) then
                    Result:= AnsiString('Сервер не вернул данные! (функция InternetQueryDataAvailable)' + sLineBreak + SysErrorMessage(GetLastError));
                  SetLength(Result, Cardinal(Length(Result)) + bytes);
                  // Получаем данные с сервера
                  InternetReadFile(FHttpRequest, @Result[Pos], bytes, b);
                  Inc(Pos, b);
                end;

              end else
                Result:= AnsiString('ОШИБКА ' + IntToStr(GetStatus(FHttpRequest)) + sLineBreak + SysErrorMessage(GetLastError));
            True: // Асинхронное чтение
              begin
                BOK:= True;
                while BOK do
                begin
                  FillMemory(@iNetBuff, Sizeof(Internet_Buffers),0);
                  inetBuff.dwStructSize := Sizeof(Internet_Buffers);
                  inetBuff.lpvBuffer := @lpReadBuff;
                  inetBuff.dwBufferLength := Sizeof(lpReadBuff)-1;
                  if not InternetReadFileEX(FHttpRequest, @inetBuff, 0, 1) then
                    if WaitAndStop then // цикл ожидания вызова callback функции для асинхронных вызовов
                    begin
                      Result:= AnsiString('Остановлено');
                      Exit;
                    end;
                  if FStop then
                  begin
                    Result:= AnsiString('Остановлено');
                    Break;
                  end;
                  lpReadBuff[inetBuff.dwBufferlength]:= #0;
                  Result:= Result + lpReadBuff;
                  if inetBuff.dwBufferLength = 0 then BOK := False;
                end;
              end;
          end;
        finally
          InternetCloseHandle(FHttpRequest); // закрываем запрос
        end else
          Result:= AnsiString('Ошибка формирования запроса (функция HttpOpenRequest)' + sLineBreak + SysErrorMessage(GetLastError));
      finally
        InternetCloseHandle(FHttpConnect); // закрываем соединение
      end else
        Result:= AnsiString('Ошибка открытия сессии (функция InternetConnect)' + sLineBreak + SysErrorMessage(GetLastError));
    finally
      InternetCloseHandle(FHttpSession); // закрываем сессию
      //InternetSetOption(nil, INTERNET_OPTION_SETTINGS_CHANGED, nil, 0);
      if FStop then
        Result:= AnsiString('Остановлено');
    end else
      Result:= AnsiString('Отсутствует подключение к сети (функция InternetOpen)' + sLineBreak + SysErrorMessage(GetLastError));
  except
    On E: Exception do
      Result:= AnsiString('Ошибка! ' + E.ClassName + ': ' + E.Message);
  end;
end;

end.
```

Comment: А если закрыть все три хэндла тоже не помогает? Закрытие и сам запрос ведь из разных потоков выполняется?

Comment: @zed все 3 хэндла пробовал, может не так закрываю? Сейчас дополню вопрос

Comment: Читать http://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wininet/asynchronous-example-application и возможно ветки там же рядом.

Comment: Если не хотите менять ваш код, можно установить таймаут на уровне 1...5 сек, и в случае если запросы обрабатываются быстро - то повисания будут до 1....5 сек и не мучаться с асинхронностью. Закрывать хандлы... ну хз как реализована либа. Закрытие внешнего WININET-хандла может не означает закрытие сокета, а сокет будет подвешивать поток. Сокеты - тоже отдельная тема надолго.

Comment: @nick_n_a, обновил вопрос. Сделал обычным способом и асинхронным, но иногда в асинхроне выдает пустую страницу...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Не дожидался утвердительного или отрицательного ответа сервера на аторизацию, поэтому пропускался этот шаг и выдавалась пустая страница. А дальше WinInet просто кэшировал авторизованное соединение и следующий запрос пропускал без проблем. 
Если запускать асинхронно, то завершить можно в любой момент. Вопрос решен, всем спасибо!

Приведу полный код, т.к. везде понемногу изменения:

```
{
Если логин с паролем не указывать (в конструкторе или после создания), то , при
необходимости будет выскакивать окно с запросом
}

unit UnitWinInet;

interface

uses
  System.SysUtils, System.Types, WinInet, Winapi.Windows;

type

  TWinInet = class
    private
      FHWND: THandle; // Хэндл вызывающего приложения
      FClientName, // Имя клиента
      FParam, // параметры запроса (которые после ?)
      FMethod, // GET, POST и др.
      FType_Access, // mime type и проч, если установлен в '', то используется по умолчанию
      FLogin, // логин
      FPass: string; // пароль
      FPostData: boolean; //True - передача параметров запроса через post data, False - через строку запроса
      FStop: boolean; // вспомогательная переменная отв. за остановку скачки
      FHttpSession, FHttpConnect, FHttpRequest: HINTERNET;
      FAsync: Boolean;
      procedure SetMethod(AMethod: string);
    public
      property HWND: THandle read FHWND write FHWND;
      property ClientName: string read FClientName write FClientName;
      property Param: string read FParam write FParam;
      property Method: string read FMethod write SetMethod;
      property Type_Access: string read FType_Access write FType_Access;
      property Login: string read FLogin write FLogin;
      property Pass: string read FPass write FPass;
      property PostData: boolean read FPostData write FPostData;
      property Async: boolean read FAsync write FAsync;
      function GetHTTP(AURL: string): AnsiString;
      procedure CancelRequest;
      constructor Create(AHWND: THandle);
  end;

implementation

uses
  Vcl.Dialogs, System.Classes, UnitTesting;
var
  completed, BOK: boolean;

procedure TWinInet.CancelRequest;
begin
  FStop:= True;
  InternetCloseHandle(FHttpRequest);
  InternetCloseHandle(FHttpConnect);
  InternetCloseHandle(FHttpSession);
  InternetSetOption(nil, INTERNET_OPTION_SETTINGS_CHANGED, nil, 0);
end;

constructor TWinInet.Create(AHWND: THandle);
begin
  FHWND:= AHWND;
  FClientName:= 'WinInet';
  FMethod:= 'GET';
  FType_Access:= 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlenDELPHId' + #13#10 +
                   'Content-Length:' + IntToStr(length(FParam));
  FPostData:= False;
  FAsync:= True;
end;

procedure TWinInet.SetMethod(AMethod: string);
begin
  FMethod:= UpperCase(AMethod);
end;

function TWinInet.GetHTTP(AURL: string): AnsiString;

  function GetHostName(AUrl: string): string;
  var
    s: string;
  begin // Имя хоста
    if Pos('https://', AUrl) > 0 then
      s:= 'https://'
    else
      if Pos('http://', AUrl) > 0 then
        s:= 'http://'
      else
        s:= EmptyStr;
    if s <> EmptyStr then
      if Pos(s, AUrl) > 0 then
        Delete(AUrl, 1, Length(s));
    if Pos('/', AUrl) > 0 then
      SetLength(AUrl, Pos('/', AUrl) - 1);
    Result:= AUrl;
  end;

  function GetScriptName(AUrl, AHostname: string): string;
  begin // URL после имени хоста
    Result:= EmptyStr;
    Delete(AUrl, 1, Pos(AHostname, AUrl) + Length(AHostname));
    Result:= AUrl;
  end;

  procedure SetFlags(AUrl: string; out Flags_connection, Flags_Request: Cardinal);
  begin // Определяем https или http
    if Pos('https://', AUrl) > 0 then
    begin
      Flags_connection:= INTERNET_DEFAULT_HTTPS_PORT;
      Flags_Request:= INTERNET_FLAG_RELOAD
                   or INTERNET_FLAG_NO_CACHE_WRITE
                   or INTERNET_FLAG_SECURE
                   or INTERNET_FLAG_IGNORE_CERT_CN_INVALID
                   or INTERNET_FLAG_IGNORE_CERT_DATE_INVALID
                   //or INTERNET_FLAG_KEEP_CONNECTION
    end else
      begin
        Flags_connection:= INTERNET_DEFAULT_HTTP_PORT;
        Flags_Request:= INTERNET_FLAG_RELOAD
                     or INTERNET_FLAG_IGNORE_CERT_CN_INVALID
                     or INTERNET_FLAG_NO_CACHE_WRITE
                     or INTERNET_FLAG_PRAGMA_NOCACHE
                     or INTERNET_FLAG_KEEP_CONNECTION;
      end;
  end;

  function GetResponseHeader(const hRequest: Pointer): string;
  var
    dwSize, Index: DWORD;
    szBuff: array [0..1024] of Char;
  begin // Возвращает заголовок ответа сервера в виде строк с CR/LF
    Index:= 0;
    dwSize:= SizeOf(szBuff);
    HttpQueryInfo(hRequest, HTTP_QUERY_RAW_HEADERS_CRLF, @szBuff, dwSize, Index);
    Result:= PChar(@szBuff);
  end;

  function GetStatus(const hRequest: Pointer): DWORD;
  var
    dwSize, dwStatus, Index: DWORD;
  begin // Возвращает заголовок ответа сервера в виде строк с CR/LF
    // Возвращает код статуса HTTP из заголовка ответа
    Index:= 0;
    dwSize:= SizeOf(dwStatus);
    HttpQueryInfo(hRequest, HTTP_QUERY_STATUS_CODE or HTTP_QUERY_FLAG_NUMBER, @dwStatus, dwSize, Index);
    Result:= dwStatus;
  end;

  function AddSecurityFlags(httpReq: Pointer): Boolean;
  var
    dwSize, dwFlags: DWORD;
  begin
    Result:= False;
    dwSize:= SizeOf(dwFlags);     // Get the current security flags
    if (InternetQueryOption(httpReq, INTERNET_OPTION_SECURITY_FLAGS, @dwFlags, dwSize)) then
    begin // Add desired flags
       dwFlags:= dwFlags
         or SECURITY_FLAG_IGNORE_UNKNOWN_CA
         or SECURITY_FLAG_IGNORE_CERT_CN_INVALID
         or SECURITY_FLAG_IGNORE_CERT_DATE_INVALID
         or SECURITY_FLAG_IGNORE_REVOCATION;
       Result:= (InternetSetOption(httpReq,
              INTERNET_OPTION_SECURITY_FLAGS,
              @dwFlags,
              dwSize));
    end
  end;

  function SendRequest(httpRequest: Pointer; AType_Access, AParam: string): boolean;
  begin
    Result:= False;
    if (FStop = False) then
      case FPostData of
        False: Result:= HttpSendRequest(httpRequest, nil, 0, nil, 0);
        True: Result:= HttpSendRequest(httpRequest, PChar(AType_Access), Length(AType_Access), PChar(AParam), Length(AParam));
      end;
  end;

  procedure StatusCallback(hInet: HINTERNET; Context: DWORD_PTR; Status: DWORD; pInformation: Pointer;
    InfoLength: DWORD); stdcall;
  var
    s: string;
  begin
    case Status of
      INTERNET_STATUS_CLOSING_CONNECTION: s:= 'Closing the connection to the server';
      INTERNET_STATUS_CONNECTED_TO_SERVER: s:= 'Successfully connected to the socket address: ';
      INTERNET_STATUS_CONNECTING_TO_SERVER: s:= 'Connecting to the socket address';
      INTERNET_STATUS_CONNECTION_CLOSED: s:= 'Successfully closed the connection to the server';
      INTERNET_STATUS_CTL_RESPONSE_RECEIVED: s:= 'Not implemented';
      INTERNET_STATUS_HANDLE_CLOSING: s:= 'This handle value has been terminated';
      INTERNET_STATUS_HANDLE_CREATED: s:= 'InternetConnect has created the new handle';
      INTERNET_STATUS_INTERMEDIATE_RESPONSE: s:=
        'Received an intermediate (100 level) status code message from the server';
      INTERNET_STATUS_NAME_RESOLVED: s:= 'Successfully found the IP address: ' + Format('%p',[pInformation]);
      INTERNET_STATUS_PREFETCH: s:= 'Not implemented';
      INTERNET_STATUS_RECEIVING_RESPONSE: s:= 'Waiting for the server to respond to a request ';
      INTERNET_STATUS_REDIRECT:
        begin
          s:= 'HTTP request is about to automatically redirect the request ' +
            Format('%p',[pInformation]);
          completed:= True;
        end;
      INTERNET_STATUS_REQUEST_COMPLETE: s:= 'An asynchronous operation has been completed';
      INTERNET_STATUS_REQUEST_SENT: s:= 'Successfully sent the information request to the server: ' +
        IntToStr(Integer(pInformation)) + ' Byte';
      INTERNET_STATUS_RESOLVING_NAME: s:= 'Looking up the IP address: ' + Format('%p',[pInformation]);
      INTERNET_STATUS_SENDING_REQUEST: s:= 'Sending the information request to the server.';
      INTERNET_STATUS_RESPONSE_RECEIVED:
        begin
          s:= 'Successfully received a response from the server: ' + IntToStr(Integer(pInformation)) + ' Byte';
          completed:= True;
        end;
      INTERNET_STATUS_STATE_CHANGE:
        begin
          s:= 'Moved between a secure (HTTPS) and a nonsecure (HTTP) site.';
          case DWORD(pInformation) of
            INTERNET_STATE_CONNECTED: s:= s + #13#10 + 'Connected state. Mutually exclusive with disconnected state.';
            INTERNET_STATE_DISCONNECTED: s:= s + #13#10 +
              'Disconnected state. No network connection could be established.';
            INTERNET_STATE_DISCONNECTED_BY_USER: s:= s + #13#10 + 'Disconnected by user request.';
            INTERNET_STATE_IDLE: s:= s + #13#10 + 'No network requests are being made by Windows Internet.';
            INTERNET_STATE_BUSY: s:= s + #13#10 + 'Network requests are being made by Windows Internet.';
          end;
        end;
    end;
    //FrmTesting.MmHTML.Lines.Add(s);
  end;

  function WaitAndStop(AReq: Pointer; AAuth: Boolean; out ASt: DWORD): Boolean;
  begin // Цикл ожидания завершения запроса
    Result:= False;
    if FAsync then // применяется только в асинхронных вызовах
      while True do
      begin
        Sleep(1000);
        if FStop or completed then
        begin
          Result:= FStop;
          if not AAuth then // обычный запрос
          begin
            ASt:= GetStatus(FHttpRequest);
            break;
          end else // авторизация
          begin
            ASt:= GetStatus(FHttpRequest);
            if (ASt = HTTP_STATUS_OK) or (ASt = HTTP_STATUS_DENIED) then
              break;
          end;

        end;
      end;
  end;

var
  bytes, b, pos: Cardinal;
  hostname, script: string;
  Flags_connection, Flags_Request: Cardinal;
  DlgError, dwFlags, Auth: DWORD;
  Status: PFNInternetStatusCallback;
  iNetBuff : Internet_Buffers;
  lpReadBuff : Array [0..255] of AnsiChar;
const
  BufferSize = 1024*4;
begin
  Result:= EmptyAnsiStr;
  FStop:= False;
  hostname:= GetHostName(AURL); // имя хоста
  script:= GetScriptName(AURL, hostname); // скрипт
  // установка доп. параметров
  if not FPostData then // если передаем параметры через строку запроса, то
    if FParam <> EmptyStr then // дополняем скрипт
      if script[Length(script)] = '?' then
        script:= script + FParam
      else
        script:= script + '?' + FParam;
  try
    SetFlags(AURL, Flags_connection, Flags_Request); // Устанавливаем флаги (http или https)
    // Открываем сессию (инициализируем WinInet)
    case FAsync of
      False: dwFlags:= 0;
      True: dwFlags:= INTERNET_FLAG_ASYNC;
    end;
    FHttpSession:= InternetOpen(PChar(FClientName), INTERNET_OPEN_TYPE_PRECONFIG, nil, nil, dwFlags);
    if FAsync then // Устанавливаем callback, если подключение асинхронное
    begin
      Status:= InternetSetStatusCallback(FHttpSession,INTERNET_STATUS_CALLBACK(@StatusCallback));
      if NativeInt(Status) = INTERNET_INVALID_STATUS_CALLBACK then
      begin
        Result:= AnsiString('Callback function is not valid');
        Exit;
      end;
    end;
    if Assigned(FHttpSession) then // Проверяем хэндл
    try // Открываем соединение
      FHttpConnect:= InternetConnect(FHttpSession, PChar(hostname), Flags_connection, nil, nil, INTERNET_SERVICE_HTTP, 0, 1);
      if Assigned(FHttpConnect) then // Проверяем хэндл
      try // Открываем запрос (передаем остаток URL (скрипт GetScriptName) в ф-ю HttpOpenRequest под параметром lpszObjectName)
        FHttpRequest:= HttpOpenRequest(FHttpConnect, PChar(FMethod), PChar(script), HTTP_VERSION, nil, nil, Flags_Request, 1);
        if Assigned(FHttpRequest) then // Проверяем хэндл
        try
          AddSecurityFlags(FHttpRequest); // Добавляем флаги
          completed:= False;
          SendRequest(FHttpRequest, FType_Access, FParam); // Отправляем запрос
          if WaitAndStop(FHttpRequest, False, Auth) then // цикл ожидания вызова callback функции для асинхронных вызовов
          begin
            Result:= AnsiString('Остановлено');
            Exit;
          end;
          if GetStatus(FHttpRequest) = HTTP_STATUS_DENIED then
          begin // Если необходима авторизация
            if FLogin <> EmptyStr then
            begin
              InternetSetOption(FHttpRequest, INTERNET_OPTION_USERNAME, PChar(FLogin), SizeOf(FLogin));
              InternetSetOption(FHttpRequest, INTERNET_OPTION_PASSWORD, PChar(FPass), SizeOf(FPass));
            end
              else
              begin
                DlgError:= InternetErrorDlg(FHWND, FHttpRequest,
                   ERROR_INTERNET_CLIENT_AUTH_CERT_NEEDED,
                   FLAGS_ERROR_UI_FILTER_FOR_ERRORS
                or FLAGS_ERROR_UI_FLAGS_GENERATE_DATA
                   //or FLAGS_ERROR_UI_SERIALIZE_DIALOGS
                or FLAGS_ERROR_UI_FLAGS_CHANGE_OPTIONS,
                   PPointer(nil)^ );
                if DlgError = 0 then
                begin
                  Result:= AnsiString('Доступ запрещен! Ввод учетных данных отменен.'
                   + sLineBreak + SysErrorMessage(GetLastError));
                  Exit;
                end;
              end;
            SendRequest(FHttpRequest, FType_Access, FParam);
            if WaitAndStop(FHttpRequest, True, Auth) then // цикл ожидания вызова callback функции для асинхронных вызовов
            begin
              Result:= AnsiString('Остановлено');
              Exit;
            end;
          end;
          case FAsync of
            False: // Обычное чтение
              if GetStatus(FHttpRequest) = HTTP_STATUS_OK then
              begin
                pos:= 1;
                b:= 1;
                while (b > 0) and (FStop = False) do
                begin // Если количество данных 0 - генерируем исключение
                  if not InternetQueryDataAvailable(FHttpRequest, bytes, 0, 0) then
                    Result:= AnsiString('Сервер не вернул данные! (функция InternetQueryDataAvailable)' + sLineBreak + SysErrorMessage(GetLastError));
                  SetLength(Result, Cardinal(Length(Result)) + bytes);
                  // Получаем данные с сервера
                  InternetReadFile(FHttpRequest, @Result[Pos], bytes, b);
                  Inc(Pos, b);
                end;

              end else
                Result:= AnsiString('ОШИБКА ' + IntToStr(GetStatus(FHttpRequest)) + sLineBreak + SysErrorMessage(GetLastError));
            True: // Асинхронное чтение
              if (Auth = HTTP_STATUS_OK) or (Auth = HTTP_STATUS_NOT_FOUND) then
              begin
                BOK:= True;
                while BOK do
                begin
                  FillMemory(@iNetBuff, Sizeof(Internet_Buffers),0);
                  inetBuff.dwStructSize := Sizeof(Internet_Buffers);
                  inetBuff.lpvBuffer := @lpReadBuff;
                  inetBuff.dwBufferLength := Sizeof(lpReadBuff)-1;
                  if not InternetReadFileEX(FHttpRequest, @inetBuff, 0, 1) then
                    if WaitAndStop(FHttpRequest, False, Auth) then // цикл ожидания вызова callback функции для асинхронных вызовов
                    begin
                      Result:= AnsiString('Остановлено');
                      Exit;
                    end;
                  if FStop then
                  begin
                    Result:= AnsiString('Остановлено');
                    Break;
                  end;
                  lpReadBuff[inetBuff.dwBufferlength]:= #0;
                  Result:= Result + lpReadBuff;
                  if inetBuff.dwBufferLength = 0 then BOK := False;
                end;
              end else
                if Auth = HTTP_STATUS_DENIED then
                  Result:= AnsiString('Доступ запрещен! Неверные учетные данные')
                else
                  Result:= AnsiString('ОШИБКА ' + IntToStr(GetStatus(FHttpRequest)) + sLineBreak + SysErrorMessage(GetLastError));

          end;
        finally
          InternetCloseHandle(FHttpRequest); // закрываем запрос
        end else
          Result:= AnsiString('Ошибка формирования запроса (функция HttpOpenRequest)' + sLineBreak + SysErrorMessage(GetLastError));
      finally
        InternetCloseHandle(FHttpConnect); // закрываем соединение
      end else
        Result:= AnsiString('Ошибка открытия сессии (функция InternetConnect)' + sLineBreak + SysErrorMessage(GetLastError));
    finally
      InternetCloseHandle(FHttpSession); // закрываем сессию
      //InternetSetOption(nil, INTERNET_OPTION_SETTINGS_CHANGED, nil, 0);
      if FStop then
        Result:= AnsiString('Остановлено');
    end else
      Result:= AnsiString('Отсутствует подключение к сети (функция InternetOpen)' + sLineBreak + SysErrorMessage(GetLastError));
  except
    On E: Exception do
      Result:= AnsiString('Ошибка! ' + E.ClassName + ': ' + E.Message);
  end;
end;

end.
```